# PHP Sqlite3 persistent connection

Tags: php, performance, sqlite

sqlite has `sqlite_popen` for persistent connection

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-popen.php

Is there a way to have persistent connection with sqlite3 ?
http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.construct.php

Please advise.